# JMeter - JSON path expressions: Extract JSON block with elements and regex with multiple conditions

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to extract JSON block where it satisfies multiple conditions. For example, extract a block which has variables with two or more desired value. Please see below given example.

```
[
  {
   id:"1",
   name:"ABC - Project 1",
   appName:"XYZ",
   state:"New",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  },

  {
   id:"2",
   name:"DEF - Project 2",
   appName:"UVW",
   state:"In Progress",
   appType:"manager",
   date:"May 13"
  },

  {
   id:"3",
   name:"GHI - Project 3",
   appName:"RST",
   state:"In Progress",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  },

  {
   id:"4",
   name:"JKL - Project 4",
   appName:"OPQ",
   state:"Expired",
   appType:"entity owner",
   date:"July 13"
  }
]
```

From the above JSON, I want to extract the JSON block where state:"In Progress" or state:"New", either of these states and it should of appType:"Owner" along with name:... Project 1; i.e. the following blocks as output:

```
  {
   id:"1",
   name:"ABC - Project 1",
   appName:"XYZ",
   state:"New",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  }
```

Which JSON Path expressions whould I use to extract:

`$.[?((@.state == "In Progress" || @.state == "New") && @.appType== "owner" && <some regex expression>)]`

But it doesn't extract any result. Is there any way to use multiple conditions for "OR/||" and "AND/&&" condition to extract that particular block. Please help!

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$.[?((@.state == "In Progress" || @.state == "New") && @.appType== "owner" && @.name =~ /.*Project 1.*/)]
```

`=~` is a [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) allowing specifying a regular expression as the filter criteria

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)